# Extracting a resource route from ui-route in remix, how to do it?

Tags: remix.run

I'd like to refactor my remix app a bit, so that I can reuse the json data in the react-native mobile app that I'm creating.

so Imagine I currently have a `place/$id.tsx` file with the following `loader` function.

```
// place/$id.tsx
export async function loader({ params }: LoaderArgs) {
  invariant(params.id, "id not found");

  const place = await getPlace({ id: params.id });
  if (!place) {
    throw new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 });
  }
  return json({ place });
}
```

this logic I'd like to move to a resource route, so that I can use it both in my remix app and mobile app.
So I'm thinking to move this loader function to a `place/$id[.json].ts` file.

How can I now get that the place details in my original ui-route loader function? do I need to call `fetch` inside the `loader` function with the full url? Or is there another way?
Feel free to advice on architecture here too, because I haven't found any examples of this and am grasping a little in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your loaders directly from the mobile app. Just add the query param `_data=route-id`. The *route id* is the path to your route file without the extension. This is how Remix calls your loader during client-side navigation and revalidation.

You can also use `npx remix routes` to display your entire route tree.

```js
const url = '/place/123?_data=routes/place/$id'
const { place } = await fetch(url).then(r => r.json())
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want to rely on an *undocumented* albeit stable (has been there since pre v1.0) technique, then you can do the following:

```js
// routes/place/$id[.json].tsx
// Resource Route

export async function loader({ params }: LoaderArgs) {
  //...
}
```

```js
// routes/place/$id.tsx
// UI Route

export { loader } from './$id[.json]'

export default function Component() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Has this approach been documented somewhere? I can't find any good information about and, which makes me fear that can easily break in the future

Comment: I don't think it's documented, but it's a known technique. The other option is to create your loader in a resource route and re-export it in the UI route.